# Can BIRT pull out data from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, birt

I'm new to BIRT. I know it has a java based reporting engine. Can this engine talk to SQL Server and pull data? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can talk to anything that has a JDBC driver. MS SQL is supported: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937724.aspx

Comment: The commercial version of BIRT from Actuate provides native SQL Server drivers.

Comment: I've used jTds http://jtds.sourceforge.net/ from java to MS-Sql before, with good results.